# How to clear back stack after launching my activity by url?

Tags: android, url

I am launching a web browser from my activity. At some state I again launch my activity with a url. But this time I don't want to see the browser again by pressing back. When the browser launches my activity I want it to look like nothing happened before to it.

Comment: Am i right that you want from A start Browser then, from browser start A again? May be you should finish A, when opening browser?

Answer (score 0):

Look at adding a flag when you launch the web intent.

This is probably what you are looking for...

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY

Comment: no luck, seems like web browser create multiple instances as it goes on further redirecting. so it doesnt have the launch info or action info on the post created instances.